# Post to Facebook page from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I am confused. My goal is very simple. My Rails app has a model NewsArticle which I want to post to a Facebook Page. I have seen a large amount of gems - such as Koala - that should be able to help me achieve that goal. I know there is a secret required for Facebook and of course some kind of authentication.

I am quite overwhelmed. I've searched for tutorials and examples, but there are so many different approaches (one using OmniAuth or Devise), but I don't get the steps.

The flow is as following. The user (Rails app) fills in the form:

1. content
2. image
3. press the button

There will be always 'one' user - the person who will manage the page.
How can I achieve this, using gems that are not obsolete by now?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: there are two approached here - either open a facebook share popup with the content and let the user login and post; or alternatively ask the user for omniauth approval so you (rails) can post on his behalf. The first one is quite simple to perform while the latter is complicated. Which would you like to accomplish?

Comment: The Rails app to post on behalf of the user is the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to post on behalf of the user you will need to grab his permission to do so and then issue a Facebook API `post` request. I'll try to list the main steps to achieve that goal, but you'll need to read the tutorials in order to perform it:
1. [Register a facebook app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/tutorials/scrumptious/register-facebook-application/). Users will see the details you provide when they authorize your site to post on their behalf.
2. Integrate [omniauth](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook) into your application. This will allow users to sign up/in to your site using Facebook. The user will grant you access to post on his behalf (assuming you provide a scope of publish_actions).
3. Integrate [Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala) into your app. Using the access_token you obtained from the user, you can now post on his wall.

Try to drill into these steps and ask finer questions if you encounter issues. Good luck.